# Unreal: I get "fatal error: 'IMotionController.h' file not found" when trying to build

Tags: dependency-management, unreal-engine4

The `IMotionController.h` file is included in my external dependencies folder in Visual Studio, so I can compile my code in the Editor, but when I try to build to an application I get:

```
fatal error: 'IMotionController.h' file not found
```

Do I need to include something in my Build.cs dependencies?

Currently, just using the defaults:

```
PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the `HeadMountedDisplay` module to the Build.cs:

```
 PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "HeadMountedDisplay", "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore" });
```